# How do I use BigInteger in a less convoluted way?

Tags: java, biginteger

So right after writing the title of this question I realized I only needed to declare one BigInteger variable and could use it both as a function argument and as a return variable (is this how it's called?)

```
public static void ex8(){
    double time_duration = 0;
    BigInteger fact; // Originally I also had an "arg" BigInteger

    long l = 100000;
    fact = BigInteger.valueOf(l); //I had arg = (...) instead of fact

    double time_before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //originally it was fact = Matematica.factorial(arg);
    fact = Matematica.factorial(fact);
    double time_after = System.currentTimeMillis();

    time_duration = time_after - time_before;

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + time_duration + " ms " + "AND\n" + "Factorial result: " + fact);  
}
```

So if I want to use BigInteger I seem to have to:

- Declare the BigInteger variable
- Declare a long variable
- Convert(?) the long variable to BigInteger and assign it
- Use it normally

**Question:** Is there any way I can simplify this process? Any way I can just use BigInteger normally without having to convert things?

Comment: `BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L)`? `BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("100000")`?

Comment: Doesn't `BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L)` work?

Comment: Yes, both work. Thanks.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? It followed the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the long in a variable before passing it as a parameter to `BigInteger.valueOf` - you can just inline it.

I think the cleanest edit of the code you presented is below.  Note that timestamps have been changed to long type declarations, and the fact variable is not reused.

```
public static void ex8(){
    BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L); 

    long time_before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BigInteger fact = Matematica.factorial(num);
    long time_after = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long time_duration = time_after - time_before;

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + time_duration + " ms " + "AND\n" + "Factorial result: " + fact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments under my submission and since no one has yet to answer correctly on the main post, I'll post it myself.

```
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("10000");
OR
BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(100000L);
```

So it becomes

```
 public static void ex8(){
    double time_duration = 0;
    BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("10000");


    double time_before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fact = Matematica.factorial(fact);
    double time_after = System.currentTimeMillis();

    time_duration = time_after - time_before;

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + time_duration + " ms " + "AND\n" + "Factorial result: " + fact);  
}
```

Much better. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

you can declare and initialize BigInteger variables in this way:

`BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1000);`

Comment: "BigInteger(long) has private access in java.math.BigInteger." You might have meant BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(10000L); (@JB Nizet's suggestion)

Comment: You can use `new BigInteger("1000")` instead.